# Aggregate and count after left join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am aggregating columns of a table to find the count of unique values. For example, aggregating
the status shows that out of 5 alerts there are 2 in open status and 3 that are closed. The simplified table looks like this:

```
create table alerts (
  id,
  status,
  owner_id
);
```

The query below uses grouping sets to aggregate multiple columns at once. This approach works well.

```
with aggs as (
select status
    from alerts
    where alerts.owner_id = 'x'
)
   select status, count(*)
   from aggs
   group by grouping sets(
      (),
      (status)
   );
```

the output at its simplest could look like this:

```
 status | count
--------+-------
        |     1
 new    |     1
```

However, now I need to aggregate additional columns from another table. This table (shown below) can have zero or more rows associated to the first table (alerts:users 1:N).

```
create table users (
  id,
  alert_id,
  name
);
```

I have tried updating the query to use a left join but this approach incorrectly inflates the counts of the alert columns.

```
with aggs as (
select alerts.status, users.name
    from alerts
    left join users on alerts.id = users.alert_id
    where alerts.owner_id = 'x'
   --  and additional filtering by columns in the users table
)
   select status, name, count(*)
   from aggs
   group by grouping sets(
      (),
      (status),
      (name)
   );
```

Below is an example of the incorrect results. Since there are 3 rows in the user table the count
for the status column is now 3 but should be 1.

```
 status |          name           | count
--------+-------------------------+-------
        |                         |     3
        | user1                   |     1
        | user2                   |     1
        | user3                   |     1
 new    |                         |     3
```

How can I perform this aggregation to include the columns from the table with a many-to-one relationship without inflating the counts? In the future I will likely need to aggregate more columns from other tables with a many-to-one relationship and need a solution that will still work with several left joins. All help is much appreciated.

edit: link to db-fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/buGD2DuJiqf9LGF9rw5EgT/2

Comment: Sample data *as text tables* would be helpful -- and perhaps a db/sql fiddle.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added a db-fiddle as suggested

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to count the number of alerts?  If so, use `count(distinct)`:

```
count(distinct alert_id)
```

Of course, you need this in `aggs`, so the `select` would include:

```
alerts.id as alert_id
```

Comment: I want a full break down of unique values for multiple columns. For example, in the alerts status column I want to know that there are 1 open, and 2 closed. Similarly other columns would show their own unique values and how many times each value occurs.